Kids eat everything in a random house and think they ate the dwellers' baby
I'm looking for the name of an old children's book where the kids smell something nice. The kids then stumble along a house full of food and eat everything in the house. They are tricked into thinking they eat the dwellers' baby.

Obligatory: where and when did you read this? The more details you give, the easier it'll be too find.

Whose baby? Presumably the kids are too young to have given birth? Do you mean a baby sibling? Also: what language was this in, was it illustrated (if so, what style), how long was it, was it in a collection of other stories, what kind of food was it, ... etc. these are the kind of clarifications that might help us answer your question. Please [edit] if you remember any further details

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
